# Centos gawk command line usage

Tags: shell, awk, quoting, gawk

I am trying to run the following command on Centos however I get an error? Unexpected token near '('

```
gawk { if($0=="id323"){print $0} } doc.txt
```

Comment: Try adding quotes around `{...}`.  Unrelated: you can just run `gawk '$0 == "id232"' doc.txt`.  Or `grep -x id232 doc.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the actual `awk` script in strong quotes to prevent the shell from seeing them and trying to parse them before passing the command in to `awk`:

```
gawk '{ if( $0 == "id123"){ print $0 } }' doc.txt
```

As an aside, you can do this slightly more elegantly:

```
gawk '$0 == "id123" { print $0 }' doc.txt
```

Comment: ... And `gawk '$0 == "id232"' doc.txt` is even more elegant, as I pointed out above. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve. This code only lets you find out whether there **are** lines containing id323 in the document. You don't gain any further information from this. So a simple grep would be sufficient.

Futhermore: I don't see that the given solution is correct at all. I think it should read:
                `gawk '$0 ~/id323/ { print $0 }' doc.txt`
                     or even shorter
                `gawk '$0 ~/id323/' doc.txt`